# Filtering List using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of customers object as follow :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CheckForResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer john = new Customer("111", "P_1", "daily",
                "create", "table_1", "03-05-2020",
                "03-05-2020", "140");

        Customer mary = new Customer("111", "P_1", "daily",
                "delete", "table_1", "03-05-2020",
                "03-05-2020", "30");

        Customer joseph = new Customer("222", "P_2", "weekly",
                "create", "table_2", "03-05-2020",
                "03-05-2020", "50");

        Customer jason = new Customer("222", "P_2", "daily",
                "update", "table_2", "03-05-2020",
                "03-05-2020", "40");

        Customer mario = new Customer("111", "P_1", "weekly",
                "create", "table_1", "03-05-2020",
                "03-05-2020", "20");

        Customer danny = new Customer("111", "P_1", "monthly",
                "update", "table_1", "03-05-2020",
                "03-05-2020", "100");

        List<CheckForResource.Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(john, mary, joseph, jason, mario, danny);

    }


    public static class Customer {

        final String Id;
        final String pCode;
        final String usageType;
        final String operation;
        final String resource; 
        final String startTime;
        final String endTime;
        final String value;

        public Customer(String id, String pCode, String usageType, String operation,
                        String resource, String startTime, String endTime, String value) {
            Id = id;
            this.pCode = pCode;
            this.usageType = usageType;
            this.operation = operation;
            this.resource = resource;
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.endTime = endTime;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return true if the list has atLeast 1  entry of each of the following clause

1. customerId="111", operation="create", usageType= "daily"
2. customerId="111", operation="create", usageType= "monthly"
3. customerId="111", operation="delete", usageType= "daily"
4. customerId="111", operation="delete", usageType= "monthly"
5. customerId="111", operation="update", usageType= "daily"
6. customerId="111", operation="update", usageType= "monthly"

How can I achieve this using steams ?

Comment: You conditions can be reduced to just `"111".equals(customer.getId()) && ("create".equals(customer.getOperation()) || "delete".equals(customer.getOperation())) && ("daily".equals(customer.getUsageType()) || "monthly".equals(customer.getUsageType()))`. And if you were to create multiple `Predicate` instances, you could still compose them using `or()`

Comment: @ernest_k This solution won't work the list doesn't have an entry for let's say customerId="111", operation="update", usageType= "monthly"

Comment: I think you missed the fact that I used `||` inside parentheses.

Comment: @ernest_k  I tried exactly this. If the list doesn't have an entry for clause6 then Predicate<Customer> p1 = c -> "111".equals(c.getId())
                && ("create".equals(c.getOperation()) || "delete".equals(c.getOperation()))
                && ("daily".equals(c.getUsageType()) || "monthly".equals(c.getUsageType())); is still returning true

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. I understood it as though you wanted to return true if at least one element of the list meets at least one of the 6 conditions. But you're instead checking that each condition is met by at least one element. It's not very clear.

Comment: why do you want to use streams for that?

Comment: you want to check that a collection contains a number of items matching criteria. That's not really what streams would excel at, since the result you are looking for depends on relationships between elements, not on rules that you can simply apply on individual elements.

Comment: how can achieve this along with one more field in the condition:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.anyMatch()`

```
Predicate<Customer> p = c -> c.getId().equals("111") &&
                        (c.getUsageType().equals("daily") || c.getUsageType().equals("monthly")) &&
                        (c.getOperation().equals("create") || c.getOperation().equals("delete") || c.getOperation().equals("update"));
boolean result = customers.stream().filter(p)
                          .map(c -> c.getId().concat(c.getOperation()).concat(c.getUsageType()))  // Map to create hash string for detect unique
                          .distinct().count() == 6;  // distinct and check the count.
```

Comment: I have multiple predicates. I can achieve this with multiple predicate

Comment: As I have 6 clauses will it be a list of predicates?

Comment: Answer updated. You can use multiple using `and/or` in one predicate

Comment: I tried your solution. It won't work if the list doesn't have an entry for let's say customerId="111", operation="update", usageType= "monthly"

Comment: I want to return true if the list has one entry for each of the clauses

Comment: Check here it's working for your case https://onlinegdb.com/r1Gg8PKj8

Comment: Hey https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/ByVErDFiI# I edited the code. In this I want the result to be fasle. But it's returning true

Comment: Why `false` ? You said  *I want to return true if the list has atLeast 1 entry of each of the following clause* means atleast one clause exists return true.

Comment: It  doesn't include the entry for the clause in which customerId="111", operation="update", usageType= "monthly"

Comment: What I want is the must have an entry for all the 6 clauses, than only return true, does it make sense?

Comment: Did you mean 1 entry for each clause total 6 entry must ? Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

- you have six different possibilities after filtering out id == 111.
- So if you construct a predicate list you can do the following
- if you have six entries then it satisfies the condition.

Create a list of predicates based on the `operation` and the `usageType`

```
List<Predicate<String>> preds = toPredicateList(
        new String[] { "create", "delete", "update" },
        new String[] { "daily", "monthly"});
```

Determine if conditions are met.

```
boolean result = 
        customers
            .stream()
            .filter(c -> c.Id.equals("111"))
            .map(c -> c.operation + c.usageType)
            .filter(preds.stream().reduce(k -> false,
                                Predicate::or))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 6;

System.out.println(result);
```

Construct the list of predicates

```
public List<Predicate<String>> toPredicateList(String[] ops,
            String[] types) {

        List<Predicate<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String o : ops) {
            for (String t : types) {
                list.add(s -> s.equals(o + t));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: how do you know the usageTypes and operations are the one the OP is looking for?

Comment: yes, but you are counting 6 arbitrary values, not checking that those values are createdaily, deletemonthly, and so on. there could be an insertyearly or whatever for all we know

Comment: Answer amended based on your observation.